# Message and variable name in one array C++

Tags: c++

Hello I wanted to ask if there is any possibility to have a message and variable name in one array? If so can you please describe, how to achieve this?

```
using namespace std;

string fname, lname;

string info[2][2] = {
    {"Write your First Name: ", "fname"},
    {"Write your Last Name: ", "lname"}
};

void getInfo(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << info[i][0];
        getline(cin, info[i][1]);
    }
    string welcomeMessage = "Hello: " + fname + " " + lname;
    printf(welcomeMessage.c_str());
}
```

This is my output when I use this function:

```
Write your First Name: FirstName
Write your Last Name: LastName
Hello:
Press Enter to close program...
```

Comment: Sounds like a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) might be what you need.

Comment: You're programming in C++, use *classes* and *member functions* instead.

Comment: And stop using `printf` for output, especially when passing user-input as the format string! What if someone write some `printf` formatting code for input?

Comment: Pointer to variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct Info {
  std::string prompt;
  std::string& saveTo;
};

std::string fname, lname;
Info info[] = {
  {"Write your First Name: ", fname},
  {"Write your Last Name: ", lname}
};

for(auto& entry : info)
{
    std::cout << entry.prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, entry.saveTo);
}
```